# Apache RegEx Redirect Not Working Properly

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, url-rewriting

I am attempting to use the following redirect code in my httpd.conf apache folder, however, every time I use it and try to connect to http://www.worldofclucky.net/fOrum it pulls up an error page saying "This page isn't redirecting properly."

The line of code is as follows:

`RedirectMatch ^/[fF][oO][rR][uU][mM]([sS]{0,1}) http://www.worldofclucky.net/forum/`

If anyone can think of ANYTHING that would help resolve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your problem is that the regex also matches the lowercase "forum" in the target, giving you an infinite loop. A negative lookbehind ought to fix that:

```
RedirectMatch ^/[fF][oO][rR][uU][mM]([sS]{0,1})(?<!forum) http://www.worldofclucky.net/forum/
```